# android edittext increase size by Dragging the corner of edittext

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android application Development i want to increase the size of Edittext by Dragging the corner of Edittext.Is there is any option available in Android? can any one suggest some solution for this? pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply. You should override `OnTouchListener`. Use something like this:

```
public class EditTextClass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private EditText txt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(YourEditTextId);
        txt.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getX() >= txt.getWidth() - 5 && event.getX() <= txt.getWidth()
            event.getY() >= txt.getHeight() - 5 && event.getY() <= txt.getHeight()) {
           txt.setWidth(event.getX()); 
           txt.setHeight(event.getY());
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya its fine thanks.i want to increase its size when i drag downward and also decrease the size while dragging upward.How is it possible?Pls reply me.

Comment: I edit it, look at this, I think you want something like this.

Comment: missing && before event.getY() >= txt.getHeight() - 5  is this right?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer above does not meet the standard requirements of good programming. An yet the "moderators" let it go to focus on more trivialities

Answer (score 0):

@Karthi just remove the if condition if you want to increase its size, this code only work for decrease the size of your view as below

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

       txt.setWidth(event.getX()); 
       txt.setHeight(event.getY());

   return true;
}
```