# How can I edit text width and height manually?

Tags: java, android

[enter link description here](https://youtube.com/shorts/4mox-z2TBuI?feature=share)How can I do it like in the picture?

[image]

How can I manually adjust the width and height of edit text using Android Studio? I want the user to adjust it according to himself.

I want to drag it to where I want on the screen.

I want a design like the picture I uploaded.

Comment: Is this a xml file? If yes you can choose to view between Code and Design. And there you can adjust the height and width as you want. But It could be better if you could paste the full xml code or write if this is in another format

Comment: I want to do everything on the phone. I want to adjust the width and height by holding and dragging. I want to add text like Canva. Then manually adjust the width and height.

Comment: maybe check this link-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477289/android-edittext-increase-size-by-dragging-the-corner-of-edittext

Comment: not working :((

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.